# Ensuring the subsequence present with probability 0.7 in n elements

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, conditional-probability, random, bayes-theorem

Ignore for my little knowledge in Mathematical Terminology
I need help in figuring out and verifying following things.

1. Lets say I have a function(fA) which returns an object of 1 Type-1 ( lets assume 0 )
   amd another function fB which returns object of Type-2 ( lets assume 1 )

Now i am generating a sequence of atmost N objects, ONE BY ONE either fA or fB

and now i am seeking help on how to ensure that Generated Sequence contains 1 with some probability.

example if even number probability is 70% ( at least 70% of number in sequence are 1 )
2 Length Sequence : {0,1} or {1,0}
3 Length Sequence : {0,1,1} or {1,1,0} or {1,0,1}

I am thinking of , calling fA, fB with required probabliity with 70% on first invocation, and then on second invocation fA,fB probability will change from 70 via bayes rule of probability. but need some guidance on how to calculate that.

P ( 2nd Invocation | 1st Invocation ) = P( 1st invocation | 2nd Invocation ) . P ( 2nd Invocation )  / P ( 1st Invocation )

need help in figuring out  P ( 1st Invocation | 2nd Invocation ) ,

Not sure if i am on right path, Seeking help on which particular area of probability i should explore more to validate

Comment: If you call $f_A$ with probability $p=0.7$ on each invocation, then, on average, the generated sequence will contain 70% of even numbers. But your goal is not precise enough: "at least 70%" is not the same as "70% on average", which is also not the same that "70% for each sequence". Note that [Even, Odd] does not contain 70% of even numbers but 50%, so what do you want exactly?

Comment: @Gribouillis, I want at have least 70% of number from fA , everytime not "on average", thats what i am trying to find , you can assume Even/Odd as just two categories of output coming out from fA and fB respectively, adding this in post just to avoid confusion.

Comment: How about doing it like this? 1. Determine the number of elements you want from fA and from fB. 2. Generate the elements from fA. 3. Generate the elements from fB. 4. Shuffle all the elements to get a random ordering.

Comment: @jakobdt, thanks for the suggestion but given my current system that i am trying to solve, fA and fB are costly operation and moreover the overall Number is also contrained by outside , kind of streaming one by one only because of cost.

Comment: To avoid a confusion you'd better to generate $0$ and $1$. Besides it is not clear what you mean by "to ensure that Generated Sequence contains EvenNumber with some probablility".

Comment: @user ,  i have removed Even/Odd mention just to avoid the confusion. Hope i am able to clarify the problem and ask that i am seeking, i am just looking for areas which i need to scratch more.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "to ensure that Generated Sequence contains 1 with some probablility". "To ensure" is something opposite to "probability". If for example you would like to have exactly 70% of the sequence be $1$ then this is possible only if the length $n$ of the sequence is a multiple of $10$ and it contains exactly $0.7n$ of $1$s.

Comment: Even if $f_A$ and $f_B$ are costly operations, @jakobdt 's idea applies: generate a priori a random sequence of N booleans containing the appropriate proportion of 1s, then for each 0 in the list, call $f_B$ and for each 1 in the list, call $f_A$.

Comment: @Gribouillis  ,that really a great idea on doing it, but what i am really interested in learning the mathematics behind this process 
if we don't generate the decision first, as there could be a situation there somebody else is controlling the number 'N'.